# Downloading all transactions from Xero to reproduce General Ledger

Tags: xero-api

I'm trying to use the Xero API to download all transactions to reproduce the general ledger in an external system so I can use it to reconcile figures within that system.

So far, I've got it downloading invoices, bank transactions, manual journals and credit notes, but it looks like bank transactions that are allocated as a payment against an invoice don't show up in the bank transactions API call.  Is this correct or am I missing something?

If I do need to download Payments, there doesn't seem to be a paging method.  Is this correct or am I missing something here?

Also, is there anything else that I need to download that might affect net movement on the general ledger?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the missing payments in bank transactions, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50898222/9195756) should help.

The [Payments endpoint](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payments) doesn't have paging according to the docs, just the If-Modified-Since header.

For our external system we started with the Journals endpoint (which should have  everything that adjusts the GL) and supplemented it where needed with additional fields from other endpoints depending on the [source type](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/Types#JournalSourceTypes).