# Xero API - Bank transactions missing

Tags: xero-api

The Xero API doesn't seem to return all bank transactions through the bank transactions endpoint.  At least some transactions that are attached to payments and transfers don't seem to be returned.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and here is what I got from Xero support:

> There are some differences between the BankTransactions API endpoint and the Bank >Transactions screen in the UI.
>
> Most importantly the endpoint does not return payments applied to invoices, expense >claims or transfers between bank accounts. Most of these can be retrieved using other >endpoints.

So it seems that you should use [Payments API](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payments) instead.

The workaround I did was to download both Bank transactions and invoices and union all transactions (I only needed references anyway), but it might make more sense to use Payments API.

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like we need to load both bank transactions and payments as well.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I was pulling out my hair why I couldn't query bank transactions that were tied to invoices.